# I have a Schengen visa. What do I need to enter Switzerland if I drive through it to get to another country?

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland

We shall be driving from Germany, through Switzerland to Italy. We may spend a night in Switzerland. I have a Schengen Visa (South African Passport)

Comment: It is unfortunate for questions like these that comments must have a minimum of 15 characters.  The answer is "nothing."

Comment: Hotels are much more expensive in Switzerland. I would suggest staying just on the non-Swiss side of the border. (The border itself is essentially un-patrolled, because of the Schengen agreement.)

Answer (score 5):

You don't require any additional visa, as Switzerland is a schengen country itself - while not a member of the EU, it is a part of Schengen (and several other EU-related agreements).

If you wish to drive on a motorway/autoroute however, [you will need a pass/sticker affixed to your car, called a Vignette](http://travel-swiss.co.uk/vignette/). This can apparently be bought either online or at a border crossing.

Answer (score 3):

Switzerland is [member of the Schengen area](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/sid_5F66C60B0566AFC44664DFBAE0CD85DE/EN/EinreiseUndAufenthalt/Schengen_node.html#doc480968bodyText4). So you don't need any extra visa to enter Switzerland.